# WebStorm doesn't update sources on local web server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I have an angular.js web app, suddenly I have noticed that when I edit sources in WebStorm and click "Run" and my app opens in chrome browser, all sources are still old ones, they didn't updated! How can I fix that?
My local webserver hosts by node.js

Comment: tried restarting the server ?

Comment: May be the browser cache. Try to go to settings (in the console) and check `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`

Comment: @atinder no, how can I do that? I'm pretty new to web dev, I thought webstorm does it for me

Comment: @Freezystem seems like it didn't help

Comment: I know WebStorm has a Client Support and a community forum. You may ask them directly. They also have a pretty concise [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea.html)

Comment: Is it still an issue? If so, please create a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As I said I'm very new to JS, and the problem was that sources in index.html were taken from example website and not from local sources, that it, pretty dumb issue, but it was a problem for me